# Wordpress loop in post admin view

Tags: wp-admin, wp-query

I'm trying to use the loop inside custom post settings.
However this results in several errors the most common being the following: when I click on a post on the admin it always goes to the the last post.

The code that I use is:

```
$original_query = $wp_query;
$wp_query = null;
$args = array( 'nopaging' => true, 'cat' => $e->cat_ID );
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
   $output .= '<option>'.get_the_title().'</option>';
endwhile; 

wp_reset_postdata();
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = $original_query;
```

any help would be very much appreciated!!
thanks